# Mongodb sort on a Text condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection like this.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62bae0858e4132ca723f00d4"),
    "appliedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-28T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "Approved"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62bae0858e4132ca723f00d4"),
    "appliedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-24T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "Applied"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62bae0858e4132ca723f00d4"),
    "appliedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-25T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "Applied"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62bae0858e4132ca723f00d4"),
    "appliedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-25T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "Absent"
}]
```

I need to sort the status by Applied 1st and then by appliedDate

```
db.leaverequest.aggregate([
     { $match: { $text: { $search: "Applied" } } },
     { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
   ]).pretty()
```

I tried the above aggregate query but its not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-vlT0A4Zqcv)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "status": 1, //sort by status
      "appliedDate": 1 //if same, use appliedDate for collision resolution
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: in that status i have value **Absent**, so that comes in 1st, i need specifically status as applied and then to be appliedDate.

Comment: You need to add a match condition at the beginning as `{ $match: { $text: { $search: "Applied" } } },` or use a simple match `{$match: {status: "Applied"}}` as  a first stage/